# MySQL: Select the highest ID for every row with the same value on another column

Tags: mysql, select, vtigercrm

suppose i have 2 related tables. The 1st one, named a, has these columns:

```
activityid
subject
date
```

The 2nd one, named b has these columns

```
activityid
crmid
```

`activityid` is what relates a and b.

I need to check for duplicate values, being multiple values having the same crmid on the table b. Using the following query:

```
SELECT y.activityid, y.subject 
FROM vtiger_activity y 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.activityid, a.crmid 
            FROM vtiger_seactivityrel a, vtiger_seactivityrel b 
            WHERE a.crmid = b.crmid 
            AND a.activityid != b.activityid) z 
ON y.activityid = z.activityid
```

i can successfully get all of these. Now i want to get all the values with the highest `activityid` between those with the same `crmid`. To explain better, if i have 3 rows with crmid = 20 and 4 rows with crmid=21, i want the highest activityid with crm=20, but also the highest activityid with crmid=21.
The following:

```
SELECT y.activityid, y.subject 
FROM vtiger_activity y 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.activityid, a.crmid 
            FROM vtiger_seactivityrel a, vtiger_seactivityrel b 
            WHERE a.crmid = b.crmid 
            AND a.activityid != b.activityid) z 
ON y.activityid = z.activityid 
WHERE y.activityid = (SELECT MAX(activityid) 
                        FROM (SELECT y.activityid, y.subject 
                            FROM vtiger_activity y 
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.activityid, a.crmid 
                                        FROM vtiger_seactivityrel a, vtiger_seactivityrel b 
                                        WHERE a.crmid = b.crmid AND a.activityid != b.activityid) z 
                            ON y.activityid = z.activityid) t)
```

can only give me the highest activityid overall.
Plus, i want to delete all duplicates but those with the highest `activityid`. What should be the right queries to do these tasks? Thanks anyone.

For those who wonder what is it, it's vtigercrm.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry It's because of not providing sample data set? Because otherwise...well thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT y.activityid, y.subject 
FROM vtiger_activity y 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.activityid, a.crmid 
        FROM vtiger_seactivityrel a, vtiger_seactivityrel b 
        WHERE a.crmid = b.crmid 
        AND a.activityid != b.activityid) z 
ON y.activityid = z.activityid 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT m.crmid,MAX(m.activityid) AS activityid 
  FROM ivtiger_seactivityrel m 
  GROUP BY m.crmid) ma
ON ma.activityid=y.activityid
```

Comment: SELECT y.activityid, y.subject 
    FROM vtiger_activity y 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(a.activityid) AS activityid, a.crmid 
            FROM vtiger_seactivityrel a, vtiger_seactivityrel b 
            WHERE a.crmid = b.crmid 
            AND a.activityid != b.activityid GROUP BY a.crmid) z 
  ON y.activityid = z.activityid

Comment: This works, although i need to read it carefully to understand what you've done! Now i will try to delete all but these 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After playing with PeterHe's solution, i found a solution to delete everything but those values:

```
DELETE vtiger_activity.*, vtiger_seactivityrel.*
FROM vtiger_activity
INNER JOIN vtiger_seactivityrel
ON vtiger_activity.activityid = vtiger_seactivityrel.activityid
WHERE vtiger_activity.activityid NOT IN (
    SELECT activityid FROM(
        SELECT m.crmid,MAX(m.activityid) AS activityid 
        FROM vtiger_seactivityrel m 
        GROUP BY m.crmid
    ) z
)
```

Thanks.